# How do I compute the separation vector between a point and a line?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Many other questions ask about how to compute the distance between a point and a line, but my question is slightly different:

how can I compute the separation vector (maybe called the height?) between a point and a line?

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is general and works in $\mathbb{R}^n $, and more in general in euclidian spaces where the scalar product is defined.

**Line as a parametric equation**

Say that your line is specified by the parametric equation:
$$
l = \{\mathbf{q} + {\mathbf{\hat n}} \,t \,\forall \,t \mbox{ in }\mathbb{R} \}
$$
for some point $\mathbf q$ and a versor $\mathbf {\hat n}$, and say that we want to compute the separation vector $\mathbf{s}$ between the point $\mathbf{r}$ and the line $l$.

We can just take the separation vector between $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf q$ and subtract its projection on the line from it, like this:

$$
\mathbf{s} = (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{q}) - ((\mathbf r - \mathbf q)\cdot \mathbf {\hat n})\mathbf{\hat n}\,.
$$

**Line defined by two points that lie on it**

If you don't have an equation for your line, but all you know is that it passes between two points (let's call them $\mathbf {x}_1$ and $\mathbf {x}_2$), then the parametric equation for your line is simply
$$
l = \left\{\mathbf{x}_1 + \frac{(\mathbf{x}_2-\mathbf{x}_1)}{||\mathbf{x}_2-\mathbf{x}_1||} \,t \,\forall \,t \mbox{ in }\mathbb{R} \right\}
$$
so that the solution above becomes 
$$
\mathbf{s} = (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}_1) - \frac{[(\mathbf r - \mathbf x_1)\cdot (\mathbf{x}_2-\mathbf{x}_1)](\mathbf{x}_2-\mathbf{x}_1)}{||\mathbf{x}_2-\mathbf{x}_1||^2}\,.
$$

If someone has the time to make a picture feel free to add it below the answer.

Comment: There is mismatched parentheses on the denominator of the last two expressions.

Comment: sorted, thanks :)